# Building a graph from a point cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a PCL Point Cloud. Basically, I need to write some code that does the following:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n65ku.jpg)

Basically, I need to build a graph/edge map of the point cloud. Where each node represents a point, and those points have pointers/edges to neighbouring points. And preferably, it cannot form a corner edge as seen in the picture. (This could be enforced by saying a point cannot have a large change in l1 norm too (taxicab distance. add all axis), not just l2 norm).

I need to do this because, it's useful for all my other algorithms. Normal computation etc.

I'm currently at a loss of how to implement this. My point cloud is unorganized. I could sort it into a KD Tree but I'm not sure if that is related to this or how I might use this.

Answer (score 1):

The graph/edge map is the same as a triangulation between the vertices.

In your case, as you only want to connect vertices which are close together, [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) will work.

The edges are the connections between vertices in your graph.

PCL has [ConcaveHull](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/hull_2d.html), which will triangulate the surface of your vertices, given an [alpha value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape). This alpha value is the maximum radius for each triangle, in your case, half the known distance between diagonal vertices.